# Bitwise or not producing expected results

Tags: java, numbers, int, byte, bit-manipulation

I have the following java code:

```
public static void main(String []args){
    int a = 1;
    byte b = -14;
    int c = (a << 8) | b;

    System.out.println(c);
 }
```

Which produces:

```
-14
```

I would have expected 498. As I understand things, the OR operation will look like this after shifting: 1 0000 0000 | 1111 0010, and I would expect this to result in an int that looks like 0000 0001 1111 0010, for a value of 498. Clearly Java is somehow sign extending the bytes when it OR's them into int c. Can anyone show me the correct way to do this?

What I'm trying to do is make an int where the least significant byte is b and the 2nd least significant byte is a.

Comment: `int c = ((a << 8) | ~(~0 << 8) & b);`.  This will give you 498.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this easily/well with bitwise operators in java. The solution is to use a ByteBuffer.

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
byteBuffer.put((byte)0);
byteBuffer.put((byte)0);
byteBuffer.put((byte)1);
byteBuffer.put((byte)-14);
byteBuffer.rewind();
int bodyLength = byteBuffer.getInt();
System.out.println(bodyLength);
```

The above code will print 498.

Answer (score 2):

If you shift everything in a byte 8 bits, you've shifted everything completely off.  ORing with a completely zeroed out byte is the same as adding zero or multiplying by 1...

Comment: If I initialize a as a short, c still evaluates to -14.

Comment: Yes, I'm left-shifting which should be correct. See the edits.

Comment: `System.out.println(a); a = a << 8; System.out.println(a)`?

Answer (score 1):

Remember `a` is `byte`. So when you do `a << 8`, won't it shift 8 positions right, effectively making it 0. It promotes the result to int. I would suggest to define `a` as `int`.

Updated:

int c = ((a << 8) | ~(~0 << 8) & b); will result in expected answer of 498

Comment: Even defining a as an int results in -14.

Comment: On second thought, it would be -14 only. `b:11111111111111111111111111110010`
`(a << 8):100000000`. So, if you are OR this, you will effectively get b

Comment: I see that this solution works for the given case. However, I'm not convinced it's very good style because no one looking at that code would have any idea what it does. So really it's up to the programmer. I personally used a ByteBuffer as in the accepted answer, but someone else may choose the bitwise operations. Obviously they're more efficient.